# Как дать приложению доступ к файлам для правки?

Tags: linux, shell, sublime-text, atom

Я правлю файлы через **Sublime Text** и если файл допустим с правами 775, 
то при <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> выскакивает окно где нужно ввести права *root*, но так как в **Sublime Text** у меня открыто слишком много файлов то я решил некоторые файлы править через **Atom** но там при нажатии <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> не появляется окно для ввода пароля.
Можно ли как-то дать **Atom** права на правку файлов из под *root* без ввода пароля, не меняя при этом права у самих файлов?
И сразу скажу, что такая команда не подходит `sudo atom какой_то _файл`, так как после перезагрузки системы нужно будет опять вводить эту команду.

Comment: Установите и запустите mc. Перейдите к файлу. F9, Файл, Расширенные права. Там всё ясно. Установить запись (w) для всех или для пользователя, который юзает атом. После сохранения таким же образо можно отобрать w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правите файлы в / директории...
и **слишком много** это сколько? у меня не меньше 1000 обычно в emacs

запустите

```
sudo  sublime &
sudo atom &
```

у вас должен быть sudo доступ, только все фылы сохраненные после этого будут иметь в качестве владельца - root